# Unify Volume Control Via Rocker

Tags: volume

Is there really no way to make the volume rocker on the side of my Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0 control ALL volumes at once, every time? 
I really don't understand why the volume rocker doesn't just control the speakers like normal volume control knobs instead of having separate controls for different applications and the rocker only working on whatever app you're in at the time. 
I want to be able to turn the volume of the device, and everything on my device, up and down, simultaneously, with the volume rocker. 
Can anyone help?
Running 4.4.2 "Toothache"

Comment: Try pressing the settings button next to the volume bar, which will expand the bar and let you drag all volumes separately

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have to do now and it's  pain in the butt. I don't want to change the volumes separately. I want to control all of the volumes simultaneously with the volume rocker. When I turn the tablet down, I want everything to be turned down. When I turn it up, I want everything to be turned up. Together. Not independently.